# Extract minima returns

Tags: r, dataframe, block, maxima

I am trying to apply the block maxima (in my case minima) approach of Extreme Value Theory to financial returns. I have daily returns for 30 financial indices stored in a csv file called 'Returns'. I start by loading the data

```
Returns<-read.csv("Returns.csv", header=TRUE)
```

I then extract the minimum returns over consecutive non-overlapping blocks of equal length (i.e., 5 days) for each index I have in my 'Returns.csv' file. For that, I do the following

```
    for (xx in Returns)                             #Obtain the minima. 
    {
    rows<-length(xx)                                #This is the number of returns
    m<-5                                            #When m<-5 we obtain weekly minima. Change accordingly (e.g., 20)
    k<-rows/m                                       #This is the number of blocks (i.e., number of returns/size of block),
    bm<-rep(0,k)                                    #which is also the number of extremes
    for(i in 1:k){bm[i]<-min(xx[((i-1)*m+1):(i*m)])}
                                        #Store the minima in a file 'minima.csv' 
    write.table(bm,file="minima.csv", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

The code extracts the minima returns for all indices correctly but when the minima are stored in the file 'minima.csv' they all appear in the same column (appended). 
What I want the code to do is to read the financial returns contained in the first column of the file 'Returns.csv', extract the minima returns over consecutive  non-overlapping blocks of equal length (i.e., 5 days) and store them in the first column of the file 'minima.csv'. Then do exactly the same for the financial returns contained in the second column of the file 'Returns.csv' and store the minima returns in the second column of the file 'minima.csv', and so on, until I reach column 30.

Comment: Please add a sample of your `Returns` data (copy & paste the output of `dput(Returns)` into your question).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply nrussell. I have thousands of datapoints. I am not sure if this is what you meant but here it is:

Comment: I added a small sample into my question. Sorry if this is not what you meant. I could've uploaded the file of there was a way. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data looks similar to this:

```
> m <- matrix(1:40, ncol=4)
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31
 [2,]    2   12   22   32
 [3,]    3   13   23   33
 [4,]    4   14   24   34
 [5,]    5   15   25   35
 [6,]    6   16   26   36
 [7,]    7   17   27   37
 [8,]    8   18   28   38
 [9,]    9   19   29   39
[10,]   10   20   30   40
```

Obviously you have more rows and columns and your data is not just the sequence of 1 to 40. To chunk each column with a size of 5 and find the minimum for each column run:

```
> apply(m, 2, function(x) sapply(split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/5)),  min))
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
1    1   11   21   31
2    6   16   26   36
```

Basically the apply is splitting m by the columns and applying the function to each column. The inner function takes each column, chunks the columns and then returns the minimum of each chunk. Your data is in a dataframe not a matrix so you need to do this before you run the command above.

```
m <- as.matrix(Returns)
```

To write this to a csv

```
> mins <- apply(m, 2, function(x) sapply(split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/5)),  min))
> write.table(mins, file="test.min.csv", sep=',', row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F)
```

Comment: It works fine now. I used write.table(mins,file="test.min.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE) to store the output. Is it the inclusion of sep=',' in your command that did the job? First time I posted a question and have to say I am impressed with the fast responses and willingness to help. Greatly appreciate your help jwilley44.